# Trying to find angle between two vectors (triangle) (HTML5 Canvas)

Tags: html, canvas, vector, geometry, angle

I am struggling to understand why my angles are returning weird angles if anything other than a right angle is drawn. I drew a basic triangle using Canvas in HTML5.

I have the html code and js code to paste here: Please can someone tell me why only these right angles adds up to 180degrees. I have set the js code to output the angles and the sum thereof to the console... so you can see what I am talking about.

You can modify the draw function code to set the position of one of the points to make a right angle.. then you will see the 180 degrees and the angles are correct.

I searched all over the internet for an explanation and checked my formulas. Cant seem to figure this one out.

Thank you very much for any help you can offer..

--- CODE FOR HTML ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Canvas - Triangle experiment</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/drawShapes.js"></script>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; }
        * { padding: 0; }

        span.markings {
            position: absolute;
        }

        div.drawingArea {
            margin: 50px 0 0 10px;
            padding: 0;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
            background: #ccc;
        }
        .coords { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 200px; }
        .coords p { position: relative; }
        .xcoord, .ycoord {  font-weight: bold; color: red; }
        #myCanvas { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="coords"><p>X: <span class="xcoord"></span></p><p>Y: <span class="ycoord"></span></p></div>
    <div class="drawingArea">
        <span class="markings A"></span>
        <span class="markings B"></span>
        <span class="markings C"></span>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="410" height="410">Your browser does not have support for Canvas. You should see:</canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

--- CODE FOR JS ---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Just for dev purposes.. show X and Y coords when inside drawingArea
    $('.drawingArea').mousemove(function(e){
        $('.xcoord').html(e.pageX -10); // subtract 10 for margin left is 10
        $('.ycoord').html(e.pageY -50); // subtract 40 bc margin top is 40
    });

    draw();

    function draw()
    {
        // Initialize context
        createContext('2d');

        // Set the style properties.
        context.fillStyle   = '#fff';
        context.strokeStyle = '#FF9900';
        context.lineWidth   = 5;

        // Set initial positions and lengths
        pts = {};
        pts.AXLoc = 60;
        pts.AYLoc = 40;
        pts.BXLoc = 360;
        pts.BYLoc = 40;
        pts.CXLoc = 100;
        pts.CYLoc = 340;

        // Get difference between points
        vector = {};
        vector.Ax = Math.abs(pts.AXLoc-pts.BXLoc);
        vector.Ay = Math.abs(pts.AYLoc-pts.BYLoc);
        vector.Bx = Math.abs(pts.BXLoc-pts.CXLoc);
        vector.By = Math.abs(pts.BYLoc-pts.CYLoc);
        vector.Cx = Math.abs(pts.CXLoc-pts.AXLoc);
        vector.Cy = Math.abs(pts.CYLoc-pts.AYLoc);

        console.log(vector.Ax);
        console.log(vector.Ay);
        console.log(vector.Bx);
        console.log(vector.By);
        console.log(vector.Cx);
        console.log(vector.Cy);

        // Find the magnitude of each vector
        vector.magA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vector.Ax, 2) + Math.pow(vector.Ay, 2));
        vector.magB = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((vector.Bx), 2) + Math.pow((vector.By), 2)));
        vector.magC = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((vector.Cx), 2) + Math.pow((vector.Cy), 2)));

        // Cos A = (A.C) / sqrt(magnitude of A) x (magnited of C)
        // This should return radian which is then converted to degrees
        // Create function once code works!
        vector.angleA = ((vector.Ax * vector.Cx) + (vector.Ay * vector.Cy)) / (vector.magA * vector.magC); 
        vector.angleA = Math.acos(vector.angleA) * (180/Math.PI);
        vector.angleB = ((vector.Ax * vector.Bx) + (vector.Ay * vector.By)) / (vector.magA * vector.magB); 
        vector.angleB = Math.acos(vector.angleB) * (180/Math.PI);
        vector.angleC = ((vector.Bx * vector.Cx) + (vector.By * vector.Cy)) / (vector.magB * vector.magC); 
        vector.angleC = Math.acos(vector.angleC) * (180/Math.PI);


        // Output test data         
        console.log('angle a = ' + vector.angleA);
        console.log('angle b = ' + vector.angleB);
        console.log('angle c = ' + vector.angleC);
        vector.allangles = vector.angleA + vector.angleB + vector.angleC;
        console.log('All angles = ' +vector.allangles ); // only adds up to 180deg if right angle??!!

        // Begin drawing
        context.beginPath();
        // Start from the top-left point.
        context.moveTo(pts.AXLoc, pts.AYLoc); // give the (x,y) coordinates
        context.lineTo(pts.BXLoc, pts.BYLoc);
        context.lineTo(pts.CXLoc, pts.CYLoc);
        //context.lineTo(pts.AXLoc, pts.AYLoc); // closes the origin point? alternate way of closing???
        context.lineJoin = 'mitre';
        context.closePath(); // closes the origin point? good for strokes

        // Done! Now fill the shape, and draw the stroke.
        // Note: your shape will not be visible until you call any of the two methods.
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();

        // Set position of markings (spans)
        $('span.markings.A').css({
                'top'   : pts.AYLoc -30,
                'left'  : pts.AXLoc -5
            });

        $('span.markings.B').css({
                'top'   : pts.BYLoc -5,
                'left'  : pts.BXLoc +10
            });

        $('span.markings.C').css({
                'top'   : pts.CYLoc -5,
                'left'  : pts.CXLoc -25
            });

        // Write markings onto canvas (degrees and lengths) 
        $('span.markings.A').html('A');  
        $('span.markings.B').html('B');  
        $('span.markings.C').html('C');         
    }

    function createContext(contextType)
    {
        // Get the canvas element.
        var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        if (!elem || !elem.getContext) {
        return;
        }

        // Get the canvas 2d context.
        context = elem.getContext(contextType);
        if (!context) {
        return;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your angle formulas a little wrong.  Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/AgmF4/.

Here are my corrected formulas:

```
    vector.angleA = (Math.pow(vector.magB, 2) + Math.pow(vector.magC, 2) - Math.pow(vector.magA, 2)) / (2 * vector.magB * vector.magC);
    vector.angleA = Math.acos(vector.angleA) * (180/Math.PI);

    vector.angleB = (Math.pow(vector.magA, 2) + Math.pow(vector.magC, 2) - Math.pow(vector.magB, 2)) / (2 * vector.magA * vector.magC);
    vector.angleB = Math.acos(vector.angleB) * (180/Math.PI);

    vector.angleC = (Math.pow(vector.magA, 2) + Math.pow(vector.magB, 2) - Math.pow(vector.magC, 2)) / (2 * vector.magA * vector.magB);
    vector.angleC = Math.acos(vector.angleC) * (180/Math.PI);
```

Comment: Manishie, so I'm kind of confused though... this was the formula i used to the letter, so not sure how you derived yours. Nonetheless, I owe you. thanks so much.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WxniMJYySc&feature=plcp

Comment: no problem! :-) i got my solution from one of my old math books from 25 years back!